# Difference between form.submit() and having an input with type of "submit"

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a HTML page containing a form. I want to make some fields `"required"`. The problem is that I'm not using a `<input type="submit">` in my form, instead, I use a Javascript function to submit the form because I need to send a Javascript variable to my server. Here is my code:

```
<form action="/toServer">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="button" onclick="submitForm(this.form)" value="Submit">
</form>

var submitForm = function(frm){
    var qstNbr = document.getElementById('hiddenField');
    qstNbr.value = someJsVariable;
    frm.submit();
}
```

So, Even is I have the `required` attribute in my input but the form is still being submitted even if I don't enter anything in the input.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JfFwC/4/) of how I want my form to behave when clicking on the button without entering anything.

Anyone knows how `form.submit()` is different from having an `<input>` of `type="submit"` ?

EDIT: After following user2696779's answer and doing a little modification, here's the final working code:

```
<form action="/toServer">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit" onclick="submitForm(this.form)" value="Submit">
</form>

var submitForm = function(frm){
    if (frm.checkValidity()) {
    var qstNbr = document.getElementById('hiddenField');
    qstNbr.value = someJsVariable;
    frm.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: its both save but in form.submit() allow you to submit form using javascript... if u want to submit form without button press then call submit via javascript

Comment: type="submit" is the native HTML form submit with no JS required. form.submit() is a way of submitting form via JS and this does not require type="submit", it could also be type="button" or you can submit the form even when you click on a link on your page.

Comment: @LShetty : If I use type="submit", How could I send my js variable to my server then ?

Comment: assign it to an input such as <input type="hidden" type="text" value="yourJSValue" /> and on the server side you could either grab post or get variable based on your form (default = get) method.

Comment: @LShetty I tried this. but the value is considered as a text and not as a JS value. If you do this and then inspect your element you'll see   it as a string "yourJSValue" and not as the value of `yourJSValue` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting using javascript will not trigger any validation. If you want to submit using a regular button + javascript and still have validation, you may use HTML5's checkValidity function to verify form fields, or the entire form.

For example, using JQuery:

```
if(!$('form')[0].checkValidity()) {
    alert('not valid');
}
else {
    $('form').submit();
}
```

See fiddle for working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Kmck/2/

Answer (score 2):

Your current HTML input button isn't a `submit` type, it's a `button` type. The `requred` attribute on your `input` element is therefore ignored. To change this, change your button's type to `submit`:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Browsers which support the `required` attribute will now display a warning when the button is clicked:

[image: Example]

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JfFwC/5/).

Comment: Not sure how that image has turned out so large, sorry about that!

Comment: Thank you, I know this, that was the same JSFiddle I shared above actually. Well, in my case, I must send a javascript variable to my server that's why I'm submitting the form with a javascript function that is executed when a user click on the button. If I change my button's type to `submit`than I couldn't send the variable to my server. Got my point ?